# simplexml_load_file() failed to open stream connection refused

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to load xml contents from a remote server.  I am trying to do this on our website hosted by Go Daddy.  I am using simplexml_load_file() to do so.  Here is the error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://remote-server/login_API_SP.php?id=Lake&p=asdfawefasdf12ds&ia=206.19.211.224): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/rjnonline/public_html/index.php on line 185
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://remote-server/login_API_SP.php?id=Lake&p=asdfawefasdf12ds&ia=206.19.211.224" in /home/rjnonline/public_html/index.php on line 185

I replaced our actual remote server with "remote-server."

The things That I tried:

1. Checked to see if `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` were on. They are both on.
2. I've tried to use cURL, I was met with an exception.
3. I typed the URL in the browser, I was able to get the results back.
4. Used `file_get_contents`, same result.
5. Checked the header information on the API.  Here it is:
   `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Running out of options here so I thought I reach out and see if anyone can help me.

Comment: It could be GoDaddy blocking the request. Are you making the request locally or from another server? I would probably try to contact their support to see if they are specifically blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

If this is true "I typed the URL in the browser, I was able to get the results back."

Then there should be no problem.

You need to fix:  "I've tried to use cURL, I was met with an exception."

There never was a link that works in a Browser that I could not get to work with curl.

Because you did not include the link to the xml, there is nothing I can do.  There are just too many variables and you offer no specifics.

You could  post the curl code that failed.

This is how it works.

```
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

GoDaddy sucks, but they are not the culprit here. Their support staff is more likely to do more harm than good.

The Problem is the request header. Both `simplexml_load_file()`  and `file_get_contents()` send bare request headers.  It is easy to detect these type of headers and drop the connection.